# Dalvik Debug Monitor not showing all logs

Tags: android

In my  Dalvik Debug Monitor `new log messages which have different tag than previous log message are displaying after erasing all previous log messages`. That means  log is clearing itself all the time and only showing a few lines. What will i do to view all Log messages??
 
[image]

Comment: I think I misunderstood the problem - are you saying that the log is clearing itself all the time and only ever showing a few lines?

Comment: Yes, log is clearing itself all the time and only showing a few lines

Comment: Yeah, I see that problem a lot, too. When that happens I usually just have to restart DDMS. It happens in the LogCat viewer in Eclipse sometimes, too. Hopefully someone here knows a better solution than restarting.

Comment: I have done that too, But no change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens a lot to me too.  As far as I know there's no easy way around it but have a look at [this python script](http://code.google.com/r/martynhaigh-colouredlogcat/source/browse) which I modified (for full disclosure this is the original [colored logcat script](http://code.google.com/p/colored-logcat/) 
 - I changed the formatting and tweaked it a bit)

or you could just use the command line:

```
adb lolcat
```

or if you're interested in a specific tag, and using unix (or cygwin as I noticed you're on the PC):

```
adb lolcat | grep TextToFind
```

P.S. yes I know I'm using `lolcat`, instead of `logcat` - both will work.  `lolcat` is just for the lulz

*** EDIT ***
You can also use [logcat filtering](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#logcat) to get the data you want from logcat.  For example I ususally use this combination:

> adb logcat MyAppTag:* *:E

this gives me all the logs which has a tag of MyAppTag and all other error and fatal messages.  This is, imo, a better way of doing it than using grep.